# How does a static attribute work with multi environments?

Tags: .net, static, attributes

Let's say you have 5 PCs and they're connected in a network. Then there's some program with a static attribute `count = 1`.
That program is installed on each PC seperatly.

What if count get changed on one of the PCs? Will it change for all PCs, or is it only changed on that one PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only changed in the one [`AppDomain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the one instance of the application on the one PC.

As long as you do not invest any additional effort, there will be no automatic synchronization even across application domains in the same instance of the application on the same PC.